# No database is running on event click

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

This code is working.

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Routes (id_object) VALUES (4)'); 
tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Routes", [], function (tx, result) 
{ alert(result.rows.item(0)['id_object']) },
function (tx, error) {alert('Неудача');} )};
```

But this doesn't working.
I added click event.

```
 <button id = "click2">Добавить в БД</button>

function querySuccess(tx, results) 
{
 $('#click2').click(addObject);

function addObject(tt){

tt.executeSql('INSERT INTO Routes (id_object) VALUES (4)'); 
tt.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Routes", [], 
function (tt, result) { alert(result.rows.item(0)['id_object']) },
function (tt, error) {alert('Неудача');} )
};
```

Why is that?

Comment: What is `tx`? Please show the code where it's opened.

Comment: second question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553098/sql-transaction-dont-working-db-transactionaddobject-errorc

Answer (score 2):

The transaction `tx` is closed shortly after the function `querySuccess` returns.
The `click` handler will be executed much later, when it doesn't have a valid transaction.

You have to create a new transaction inside the `click` handler.